# Can't build click package (Ubuntu SDK)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, compiling, ubuntu-sdk

Whenever I try run an app via the Ubuntu SDK it gives the following error under the "Compile Output" tab:

> Makefile:391: recipe for target 'install_desktop_file' failed
>   09:39:38: The process "/home/sander/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/ubuntu-sdk/ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/make" exited normally.
>   
> **09:39:38: Could not find the manifest.json file in /home/sander/tools/build-Tools-Ubuntu_Device_GCC_armhf_ubuntu_sdk_15_04_vivid-Release/.ubuntu-sdk-deploy.
>   
> Please check if it is added to the install targets in your project file**
>   
> Error while building/deploying project Tools (kit: Ubuntu Device (GCC armhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-vivid))
>   
> When executing step "UbuntuSDK Click build"
>   
> 09:39:38: Elapsed time: 00:06.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! I've just deleted all the .user files in the project folder.